# passing a variable in SOQL select statement with python and simple-salesforce

Tags: python, date, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

I am trying to pass a variable into SOQL statement, I am using simple_salesforce library. I only need to grab the data when CreateDate of the Opportunity is > than yesterday, yesterday's date is saved in `last_run_day` variable. Below is my code:

```
yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)
last_run_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S"+"Z")

sf_data = sf.query_all("SELECT ID, Name FROM Opportunity where probability > 0 AND CreatedDate > '%s' AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL ORDER BY AdPoint_Id__c" % last_run_date)
print(sf_data)
```

Gives me an error: field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `strftime` actually returns a string.
To find out the object type you can use the `type` method

You can use this line of code in your program to check the type `print(type(last_run_date))` it will return `<class 'str'>` which means its a string object.

So in your query you cannot assign string to a datetime.

You can try using the below code

```
import datetime
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
sf_data = sf.query_all("SELECT ID, Name FROM Opportunity where probability > 0 AND CreatedDate > '%s' AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL ORDER BY AdPoint_Id__c" % yesterday)
print(sf_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)

sf_data = sf.query_all("SELECT ID, Name FROM Opportunity where probability > 0 AND CreatedDate > YESTERDAY AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL ORDER BY AdPoint_Id__c")

print(sf_data)